# Sklearn model keeps increasing in size

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network

I'm using a simple neural network to predict three outputs. My model is `MultiOutputRegressor(MLPRegressor())`

I'm training the model with one example at a time with `partial_fit` method.

However, when using `pickle.dump` to save the model, the size of the model keeps increasing over time. The more examples I train with, the larger the model size.

Neural network with adam optimizer should remain constant size. So why does it keep increasing?

Here's a reproducible example:

```
import os
import pickle
from os.path import dirname, join

from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor

path = join(dirname(__file__), "test.p")

m = MultiOutputRegressor(MLPRegressor())
for _ in range(10):
    for _ in range(1000):
        m.partial_fit([[0,0,0,0,0,0]],[[0,0,0]])
    with open(path, "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(m, f)
    print(os.stat(path).st_size)
```

output

```
157501
250507
343513
436519
529525
622531
715537
808543
901549
994555
```

Comment: I'm not sure. But I think you will APPEND a new set of model parameters to the end of the old ones every time you run the code `pickle.dump(m,f)`. Also, notice that the difference between two consecutive lines is constant. It might help spot the bug.